# Looping through lists in global environment in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to get the summary statistics of 125 row matrices in the global environment with lengths 1x919296 each. i would like to create a loop to get the same but was not able to do. i am also trying to do the K-means cluster analysis for the matrices as well. I would like to get some guidance as i am new to R. Thank you

I tried using simple for loops but not able to get the desired results

Comment: Why are these matrices in the global environment and not combined in a list? Why does your question title mention lists but then you state that you have matrices?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Roland I am analysing a video that is converted into a Image and then into a RGB matrix in Matlab and imported into R, so the global environment has a list of each frame (about 150 frames in total) with 3 matrices for Red, Green and Blue. I need to get the summary statistics (mean, standard deviation, median etc) for all the matries in all the 125 frames.

Answer (score 0):

This shows the general approach:

```
m1 <- matrix(1:16, 4)
m2 <- matrix(1:4, 2)

results <- list()
for (i in 1:2) {
  results[[paste0("r", i)]] <- colSums(.GlobalEnv[[paste0("m", i)]])
}

results
```

Of course, the matrices should not be directly in the global environment but in a list. Then you could just iterate over the list (as shown above with a `for` loop or more conveniently by using `lapply`). You could use `mget` to combine the matrices into a list but it would be better to put them in a list when they are created.